# What is the number of x-intercepts in this graph of sine?

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions

The function : $y=3-4\sin(2\pi x-3\pi)$ .. how many $x$-intercepts  over the interval $[0,2]$?

I am confused if they're **3 or 5**

because there are 3 $x$-intercepts that are really intercepting $x$-axis

but there are 2 that **stop** at the $x$-axis and **don't continue**

I hope you get my point ..

Comment: What do you mean by stop? The graph looks like this:
http://bit.ly/1nWqU9R

Comment: I meant that when the graph reaches to the left limit of the given interval it stops at the x-axis and it doesn't continue going down ? my question is .. when the graph reaches to 0 at x-axis from the right to left -- will that point be considered as x-intercept or not?